# Supporting a fellow PhD student with newly diagnosed ADHD - inattentive type

Tags: phd

A fellow PhD student told me that they have been diagnosed with ADHD (inattentive type). This seems to have been an assessment done for work-related purposes as they are a part-time student. I am not familiar with inattentive type ADHD as I am more familiar with hyperactive ADHD as I knew of fellow high school students with hyperactivity.

Unfortunately, my colleague is struggling to find a psychiatrist comfortable with ADHD prescription and there does not seem to be clinical services focused on adult ADHD in the local area. I am also not sure how useful medications are especially for adult inattentive symptoms.

**The question** : I am wondering how useful any interventions are - accommodations, student support, therapy are? 
I will not be advising or directing my colleague but they have asked for support. They are not ready to tell their supervisor as yet.

~ The most similar question I could find on SE was - [What specific techniques can help someone facing mental health problems (depression, anxiety, ADHD) have a productive academic career?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47783/what-specific-techniques-can-help-someone-facing-mental-health-problems-depress) However I think ADHD deserves a full discussion especially this focus on the inattentive type.

~ Elizabeth has made some useful answers related to ADHD as well - [Academics with ADHD or autism: What workplace accommodations have helped you?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125355/academics-with-adhd-or-autism-what-workplace-accommodations-have-helped-you)

[Supervising a research student with attention problems - what can I do to help the student be more independent?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94398/supervising-a-research-student-with-attention-problems-what-can-i-do-to-help-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This is confusing.  The question implies you and the person with ADHD are both faculty, but the explanation says you are both PhD students.

Comment: Therapy and medication are best left to the professionals and are off-topic on this site.  Accommodations and student support are not your business if you are a student.  That's the business of the PhD supervisor and disability office.  Do respect other students' privacy.

Comment: Yeah they asked for my help and I am just keen to look at the research too. I have edited the question. I am aware that I would not be giving clinical advice...

Comment: Also later over the weekend I am keen to summarise some of the research studies and discussions I have had with people...

Comment: I have inattentive ADHD and medication fixed my life. Therapy is useless.

Comment: What is the question? Independent about what?   The question is off-topic (refer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). And even if we'd like to help there is not a defined enough question about the current process or even if the answer is how to help you encourage them or what the supervisor can do, or what.

Comment: Thanks @deags - is there any evidence that any interventions are worthwhile to improve the rates of university progression for people with ADHD. Especially for newly diagnosed ADHD...

Comment: @MattSamuel Talk therapy can be very useful for addressing long-term psychological issues arising from the blame, guilt feelings, or self-defeating behavior that ADHD adults have often internalized before they get a correct diagnosis. It's true that it's much less helpful for day-to-day strategies in managing ADHD.

Comment: Where did they get the diagnosis? The diagnosing practitioner should know local psychiatrists who know how to medically treat ADHD. They could also try asking at the student health center. As for clinical services for ADHD other than medication management, that's going to be harder if you're not in a major metropolitan area, plus it's difficult to get insurance to pay for it. If your classmate wants one-on-one coaching, it might be necessary to look for it online. Some ADHD coaches will do telephone or internet coaching.

Comment: Thanks Elizabeth. Your answer is very helpful. A private psychologist has made the diagnosis. The hunt is now on for a prescribing psychiatrist. Much appreciated!

Comment: In the US, many insurance plans seem to require that a diagnosis be made before Age 7 or 8 to qualify for pre-authorization.  So while I'm not too familiar with the specifics, I suspect that this might be a complicating factor.

Comment: They might also seek pharmaceutical advice about over-the-counter options.  For example, I've heard that caffeine can help.

Comment: Finally, it may help to understand the condition.  My personal understanding is that ADHD is sorta like an absence of a deep-seated respect for authority or a compulsion to follow orders/directions.  For example, if a non-ADHD person is like a country with strong governmental control, then an ADHD person is more like a country with a strong focus on individual freedom.  Then the person themself is like the government: the non-ADHD person can more directly control what the country does, while the non-ADHD person must motivate themself more indirectly.

Comment: It's also worth understanding that ADHD isn't all bad.  I mean, the big thing that hurts people with ADHD is that their lack of internal directness makes them less able to participate in external social phenomena that require it, e.g. an ADHD person _can_ complete a standardized exam, but unlike a non-ADHD person, they can't internally compel themselves to focus exclusively on the exam for the short window in which it's given.  The up-shot is that they enjoy the benefits that come from free-market economies over government-controlled ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was diagnosed with severe inattentive ADHD when I was 12ish. I'm now 32 and am an instructor at a university. I've dealt with it in all ways and am not shy about it.

Medication worked for me. It might not for everyone. ADHD is also over-diagnosed, or was a decade or two ago. It's also a real pain in the *** to get medication in the USA because it's a controlled substance. It's a pain to travel with because my medication is illegal in some countries. *But it works for me.*

**Your friend should find a psychologist who can diagnose ADHD. After that, getting medication is normal. You should encourage your friend to explore the support services offered by your institution. They'll be experienced in how to support your friend and will be able to direct them to other resources and psychologists.**

Good luck!